# env.password is set in fab file but process is still asking sudo password multiple times

Tags: python, fabric

I have a fabfile.py for my django project that I'm using for auto-deploy.  I use getpass to prompt the user for sudo password on the server, then set env.password, however, when I run other commands, like run('sudo mkdir foo/bar') I get prompted for sudo password with each time a sudo command is run.

Here is the code (sorry for the horrible code block, still a new poster to the site):

```
 def initial_deploy(*args, **kwargs):
        args = dict([(x, True) for x in args] + kwargs.items())
        env.user = args.get('user','webiken')
        password = getpass('Please provide sudo password for user %(user)s ' %               dict(user=env.user))
        if password:
          env['password'] = password
          env['sudo_prompt'] = 'sending sudo password...'
         app_name = args.get('app','webiken-demo')
         now = datetime.now()
            year = now.year
        dt = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
        cmd = 'sudo rm -rf /opt/%(app_name)s' % dict(app_name=app_name)
        run(cmd)
        cmd = 'sudo mkdir -p /opt/%(app_name)s/%(year)s/' % dict(
    app_name = app_name,
    year = year
    )
        run(cmd)
        cmd = '/opt/%(app_name)s/%(year)s' % dict(
        app_name = app_name,
        year = year
    )
        with cd(cmd):
    run('sudo git clone git@localhost:%(app_name)s.git %(now)s' % dict(
        app_name = app_name,
        now = dt
    ))
        run('sudo ln -s /opt/%(app_name)s/%(year)s/%(now)s /opt/%(app_name)s/current' % dict(
    app_name = app_name,
    year = year,
    now = dt
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write your own code to request a password; try using Fabric's [`sudo` command](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.sudo) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem probably cause by the newlines,try this:

```
f = open("../pass.txt", 'r')
password=str(f.read()).strip()
f.close()

print password
env.user = 'user'
env.password = password
```